# How to multiply two polynomials in $GF(3)[x]_{x^2+1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, galois-theory, finite-fields

We have the field $GF(3)[x]_{x^2+1}$ and want to multiply the two polynomials $2x+1$ and $2x+2$.

I understand that $GF(3)[x]_{x^2+1} := \{0,1,2,x,2x,x+1,x+2,2x+1,2x+2\}$. I'm not sure what the best method for multiplying polynomials is (without the table).

I first proceed like so:
$(2x+1) * (2x+2) = 4x^2+4x+2x+2 = x^2+2$

Now the polynomial can't have a degree bigger than 1 in our field, so I'd have to devide the result I'm getting by $x^2+1$.

$x^2+2 = (x^2+1) + 1$ so we have a remainder of $1$. Is the final result $= 1$? or am I doing the computation wrong from the get go?

In general, the result has to be an element of our field. So do you just take the remainder as the final result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's ok. But even simpler, for this special case, just replace any occurrence of $x^2$ in the product by $-1$. And of course, always reduce the coefficients, mod $3$.

Comment: @quasi could you please elaborate on this? I don't understand why that would work?

Comment: Isn't -1 = 2 in $GF(3)$?

Comment: When modding out by $x^2 + 1$, $x^2$ is congruent to $-1$. More precisely, $x^2 \equiv -1$ modulo the ideal $(x^2 + 1)$.

Comment: Sure, $-1=2$, but it doesn't matter (since they're the same).

Comment: Could you please explain or link me to the theorem that would say tjat $x^2$ is congruent to -1? I don't really understand this. Thank

Comment: @DariusTheGreat: This is something that could be an exercise in whatever source you're learning from. e.g. "Prove $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {x^2 + 1}$" or "Find the reduced representative of $x^2$ modulo $x^2 + 1$".

Comment: If $I$ is an ideal, $a \equiv b \;\text{mod}\;I \iff a-b \in I$, hence, using $a=x^2,\;b=-1,\;I=(x^2+1)$, it follows that $x^2 \equiv -1\;\text{mod}\; (x^2+1)$. Alternatively, reduce $x^2$ by long division. If you divide $x^2$ by $x^2+1$, what is the remainder?

Comment: @quasi thanks this helps me and answers my question aswell

Comment: Because we declare $x$ (or, more accurately, its coset) to be a zero of the polynomial $x^2+1$ you can just think of $x$ as if it were the more familiar zero of that polynomial, $x=i$. So you multiply like
$$(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(bc+ad)i.$$ Using $i^2=-1$ when necessary, and reducing $ac-bd$ and $bc+ad$ modulo three.